# TODO project is not woking properly

Tags: reactjs

- **Components** ->
- Box
- Todolist
- Add
- AddModal
- Main component App

But it is not working that is when I add a new task. It does not get added properly.

I think I cannot use this.setstate twice in a function.

Hope I am correct

Here is given the main component.

App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Box from './Components/Box';
import Add from './Components/Add';
import Todolist from './Components/Todolist';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        lists: '',
        inputValue: '',
        itemArray: []
    }
}

  onAddTask = () => {
    this.setState ({
        lists: this.state.inputValue
    });
    const item = this.state.itemArray;
    const title = this.state.lists;
    item.push({ title  })
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      itemArray: [...prevState.lists, title]
    }))
}

updateInputValue = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    inputValue: event.target.value
  });
}

  render() {

    let length = this.state.itemArray.length;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Box createTodo = {
          <div>
            {this.state.itemArray.map((itemArr) => {
              return (
                <div className="box">
                  <Todolist tasks = {itemArr} />
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </div>
          }>
        </Box>
        <Add addTask = {this.onAddTask} inputValues = {this.updateInputValue} inputV = {this.state.inputValue}  />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting event on updateInputValue fuction?

Comment: hyperlinks fixed

Comment: Pl add all the code here or a working app in codesandbox. It will make debugging easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `addTasks` function is not correct, you are mixing up things here.
In your `inputValue` you save the current value from the input field right? So if you write the following

```
this.setState({
    lists: this.state.inputValue
});
```

you set your todo list to this single value. And your todo list is not an array anymore.

Secondly, state is imutable. So if you write the following

```
this.state.itemArray.push({ title });
```

the state will not be updated. What you actually want is the following:

```
onAddTask = () => {
    this.setState({
      itemArray: [...this.state.itemArray, this.state.inputValue]
    })
}
```

And I'm not sure what the `lists` property on the state is for. You don't use it anywhere besides in your `onAddTask` function. So I guess you can remove it.

Comment: But does it not mean the same  `this.setState(prevState => ({
      itemArray: [...prevState.lists, title]
    }))`

Comment: No, because your `lists` property on your state object is of type string. And you want an array right?

Comment: Next time you ask a question on SO you might use a tool like [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) (or the internal SO sandbox) to show your app. Makes it easier to debug for people.